# Comparing two sheets in Excel Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to create a macro to compare two versions of a report in order to check if historical data is changed when creating the new report.

I want to loop through the Used Range of one sheet and then compare each cell in that range with the same address in another sheet.

This is the code so far:

```
Sub Compare_Report()

    Dim vRange As Range
    Dim v_Rangeversie As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrorCatch
    Debug.Print Now

    Set v_Rangeversie = Worksheets("VorigeVersie").UsedRange

    For Each v_range In Worksheets("1. Overzicht").UsedRange
        For Each vCell In v_range

            Debug.Print vCell.Address

            'If  vCell.Value != v_Rangeversie.Range.Cell(vCell.address)
            'Then

            '    Debug.Print "Ongelijk"
            '    Cells are different.
            '    varSheetB.Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            '    varSheetB.Cell.Font.Color = 2
            'End If
        Next
    Next

    Exit Sub

ErrorCatch:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

I can't get this If-statement to work:

```
        'If  vCell.Value != v_Rangeversie.Range.Cell(vCell.address)
```

What do I miss? Please help.

Regards, Jan

Comment: `!=` does not work in vba use `<>` instead

Comment: And put the `Then` on the same line as the `If`

Comment: `Cell` doesn't get address of the cell, you need to use `Range(vCell.Address)` also need to add `.Value` at the end. If you want to write in another line (incompleted lines) need to use `_` at the end of that line (for if as @ScottCraner mentioned and debug.print).

Comment: Hi Scott, i noticed that error too :-) Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this:

```
Sub compareSheets(shtBefore As String, shtAfter As String)
 'Retrieved from MrExcel.Com July 2012

 Dim mycell As Range
 Dim mydiffs As Integer

   For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange

     If Not mycell.Value = _ 
          ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
 'Or use "mycell.Value <> othercell.Value"
         mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
         mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

     End If

   Next

   MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtAfter).Select

End Sub
```

It highlights the differences in yellow.

For using it you should call it within another sub like this:

```
Sub highlight_differences()
    Call compareSheets("1. Overzicht", "VorigeVersie")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional formatting alternative. You may want to write it in VBA in order to call it after generating the report... It's a one-liner:

```
Worksheets("1. Overzicht").UsedRange.FormatConditions.Add _
  (xlExpression, , "=A1<>VorigeVersie!A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```